# ElasticSearch Frequent Updates

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a rather difficult set of requirements for our search engine replacement and they go as follows.

- Every instance will have a unique schema, we have multiple client installations that we don't control that have varying data structures
- Frequent updates, it's not uncommon for every record to have a field be updated in a single action. Some fields are updated frequently, others are never changed
- Some of our fields can be very large (50mb+) though these are never changed and are rare in a data set.
- We'd like to have near real-time search if possible

We're looking at making the fields that are updated semi-frequently/frequently into child documents. The issue with this is that we have a set of tags that change quite frequently on the record that we want to search against in near real time. There is a strong expectation in our application that when this data is modified that searching immediately reflect that. We've tried child documents, but they don't seem to update as quickly as we'd like over a large data set.

So the questions are as follows:

- Are there strategies I'm not aware of for updating child documents quickly? Maybe a plugin? Right now we're only using the RESTFUL interface
- Would it be better to store the data that isn't frequently changed in ES but keep the tags in a database? Possibly creating a plugin in ES that maps the two together? Would this plugin in be difficult? Ideally, we'd be able to mix our searches together (Tags+regular ES queries) in a boolean fashion including the tags stored in a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully this will be helpful to other people in this situation, here is the solution I came up with.

- Use Child/Parent documents
- There was a single parent that contained static information for the record that rarely/never changes (bulk of the data indexed)
- Create child documents for other data I wanted to index so they could be indexed independently of the primary document

Since I had split the record data I wanted to index into static and non static documents, then broke that non static data into further child documents I was able to create a high throughput indexer. The total number of records to be indexed were split into sub chunks, which were then further split into their child document types. I would split these chunks out to various indexer instances which would then be only limited by the throughput of the data source or the ES cluster in determining how many documents could be indexed per second.

This was all done through the bulk API. Keeping the static data away from the frequently changing data allowed the frequently changed data to be updated quite quickly and this speed was only limited by the available hardware. It was a little tougher to craft queries using the child document clauses and aggregates but everything seemed to work.

Notes

- There is a performance penalty to using parent/child documents which was a non issue for us considering what ES gave us over our previous solution but it may cause issues for other implementations.